# How to stop ticks in NetLogo and show in monitor

Tags: netlogo

I modeled an evacuation behavior form a building as in the figure:[image]

```
globals [
wall
window
door
goal-x goal-y
n
]

patches-own [patch?
walls
windows
doors]

turtles-own [direction
fast?
fear?
other-nearby]

to setup
  ca

setup-patches

   set-default-shape turtles "person" ;like people
   ask n-of number-room1 patches with [pxcor < 71 and pycor < 79 and pxcor >         
   0 and pycor > 50 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches = room1
 [sprout 1 [
  if [count turtles-here] of neighbors4 = 3 [congest]
  set size 10              ;; setting turtle size
  facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
  set direction 1
  set color yellow     ;initial color


  if xcor mod 2 != 0 [set fast? false]
  if xcor mod 2 = 0 [set fast? true]
  if turtles != red [set fear? false]

]
]

  ask n-of number-room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room2
 [sprout 1 [
  if [count turtles-here] of neighbors = 3 [congest]
  set size 10              ;; setting turtle size
  facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
  set direction 1
  set color yellow     ;initial color
  if xcor mod 2 != 0 [set fast? false]
  if xcor mod 2 = 0 [set fast? true]
  if turtles != red [set fear? false]

]
]

ask n-of number-room3 patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0 and pcolor = black]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room3
 [sprout 1 [
  if [count turtles-here] of neighbors = 3 [congest]
  set size 10             ;; setting turtle size
  facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
  set direction 1
  set color yellow     ;initial color
  if xcor mod 2 != 0 [set fast? false]
  if xcor mod 2 = 0 [set fast? true]
  if turtles != red [set fear? false]
  ]
]



 ask n-of number-room4 patches with [pcolor = brown]  ; makes turtles sprout on black patches= room4
[sprout 1 [
  if [count turtles-here] of neighbors = 3 [congest]
  set size 10              ;; setting turtle size
  facexy 124 79 ; initial direction faceing
  set direction 1
  set color yellow     ;initial color
  if xcor mod 2 != 0 [set fast? false]
  if xcor mod 2 = 0 [set fast? true]
  if turtles != red [set fear? false]


  if pxcor <= 120 and pxcor >= 90 and pycor = 12 [walk1]
  if pxcor <= 120 and pxcor >= 90 and pycor = 24 [walk1]
  if pxcor < 90 and pxcor >= 85 and pycor >= 12 and pycor < 24 [set heading 0]

]
]
fear ;calls function fear
reset-ticks

end

to walk1 ;function earlier called

ifelse ((random 2) = 0); to allow turtles randomly decide if they will go 
left or right in rows.
[
  go-left
]
[
  go-right
]

end

to go-left
set heading 90

end
to go-right
set heading 270

end


to congest

stop

 end

 to setup-patches

 draw-wall;wall, Windows and Doors
 draw-exit ; Doors
 draw-row ; sitting area
 draw-corridor-cafeteria



 ;Labels
  ask patch 41 60[
  set plabel-color white
  set plabel "Room1 = Office"
   ]
  ask patch 95 60[
  set plabel-color white
  set plabel "Room2 = Management"
  ]
  ask patch 77 44[
  set plabel-color white
  set plabel "Corridor"
  ]
  ask patch 41 18[
  set plabel-color white
  set plabel "Room3 = Meeting Room"
  ]
  ask patch 112 18[
  set plabel-color white
  set plabel "Room4 = Cafeteria"
  ]

  end

  to draw-wall
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 120 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 79]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 129 and pycor = 79]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 132]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 0]
  [set pcolor blue]

  ask patches with [pxcor <= 34 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 0]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 43 and pycor = 0]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 112 and pxcor >= 109 and pycor = 50]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 50 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 50]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 84 and pxcor >= 79 and pycor = 36]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 70 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = 36]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 132 and pxcor >= 93 and pycor = 36]
  [set pcolor blue]

  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 50 and pxcor = 71]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 79 and pycor >= 50 and pxcor = 112]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pycor <= 36 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 82]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 100 and pxcor >= 59 and pycor = 50]
  [set pcolor blue]
  end


 to draw-exit
 ;room1
 ask patches with [pxcor < 59 and pxcor > 50 and pycor = 50]
[set pcolor green]
;room2
 ask patches with [pxcor < 109 and pxcor > 100 and pycor = 50]
 [set pcolor green]
;room3
 ask patches with [pxcor < 79 and pxcor > 70 and pycor = 36]
[set pcolor green]
;room4
ask patches with [pxcor < 93 and pxcor > 84 and pycor = 36]
[set pcolor green]

;main exit
ask patches with [pxcor < 130 and pxcor > 120 and pycor = 79]
[set pcolor red]

 ;second exit
 ask patches with [pxcor < 43 and pxcor > 34 and pycor = 0]
 [set pcolor red]

 ask patches with [pxcor < 132 and pxcor > 112 and pycor = 50]
 [set pcolor 1]
 end

 to draw-row
 ask patches with [pxcor <= 123 and pxcor >= 93 and pycor = 12]
 [set pcolor brown]
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 123 and pxcor >= 93 and pycor = 24]
 [set pcolor brown]
 end

 to draw-corridor-cafeteria
 ask patches with [pxcor <= 93 and pycor <= 24 and pxcor > 82 and pycor >= 12] [set pcolor 2]
ask patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor <= 24 and pxcor >= 123 and pycor >= 12] [set pcolor 2]
end

  to go
ask turtles with [pcolor != red] [walk] ;asks turtles with patch color not equal to red carry out function walk
spread-fear
tick
end

  to spread-fear ; When an agent with fear is near another agent withiut fear, the other has a chance of also getting scared according to slider on interface, spreadfear
ask turtles with [fear? = true and pcolor != red]
[ ask other turtles-here with [fear? = false]
[if (random-float 100) < spreadfear [getscared]]
]
end

to getscared ;changes turtles
set color red
set fear? true
end

 to fear
;ask some initialy scared turtles to get scared
ask n-of initially-scared-1 turtles with [size = 10] [getscared]
ask n-of initially-scared-2 turtles with [size = 10] [getscared]
ask n-of initially-scared-3 turtles with [size = 10] [getscared]
ask n-of initially-scared-4 turtles with [size = 10] [getscared]
end

  to walk
  let room1 patches with [pxcor <= 70 and pycor <= 78 and pxcor >= 1 and pycor >= 51]
   let room2 patches with [pxcor < 112 and pycor < 79 and pxcor > 71 and pycor > 50]
  let room3_lft patches with [pxcor < 20 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 0 and pycor > 0]
 let room3_rgt patches with [pxcor < 82 and pycor < 36 and pxcor >= 20 and pycor > 0]
 let room4 patches with [pxcor < 132 and pycor < 36 and pxcor > 82 and pycor > 24]
 let corridor_1 patches with [pxcor <= 70 and pycor <= 50 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor >= 36]
  let corridor_2 patches with [pxcor <= 131 and pycor <= 50 and pxcor >= 71 and pycor >= 36]
  ask turtles-on room1
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor < 59 and pxcor > 50 and pycor = 51]
   ]
   let exit-room-1 patches with [pxcor < 59 and pxcor > 50 and pycor > 50 and pycor <= 51]
   ask turtles-on exit-room-1
  [set heading 180]
  ask turtles-on room2
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor < 109 and pxcor > 100 and pycor = 51]
 ]
 let exit-room-2 patches with [pxcor < 109 and pxcor > 100 and pycor > 50 and pycor <= 51]
 ask turtles-on exit-room-2
[set heading 180]
ask turtles-on room3_rgt
[ face one-of patches with [pxcor < 79 and pxcor > 70 and pycor = 35]
]
 ask turtles-on room3_lft
[ face one-of patches with [pxcor = 70 and pycor > 0 and pycor < 36]
]
let exit-room-3 patches with [pxcor < 79 and pxcor > 70 and pycor >= 35 and pycor < 36]
  ask turtles-on exit-room-3
  [set heading 0]
  ask turtles-on room4
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor < 93 and pxcor > 84 and pycor = 35]
  ]
   let exit-room-4 patches with [pxcor < 93 and pxcor > 84 and pycor >= 35 and pycor < 36]
 ask turtles-on exit-room-4
 [set heading 0]
 ask turtles-on corridor_1
 [set heading 90]
  ask turtles-on corridor_2
    [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 131 and pxcor >= 113 and pycor = 50]
     ]
     let mainexit patches with [pxcor <= 131 and pycor < 79 and pxcor >= 113 and pycor >= 50]
 ask turtles-on mainexit
  [ face one-of patches with [pxcor <= 129 and pxcor >= 121 and pycor = 79]
  ]
    let mainexitdoor patches with [pxcor <= 129 and pxcor >= 121 and pycor = 79]

 if fear? = true [fd .5]
 if fear? = false [fd .8]
 ask turtles-on mainexitdoor [evacuate]
 end

to evacuate
set color green
if all? turtles [pcolor = green] [ stop ]
end
```

I can't stop ticks after all agents arrive at main exit door and I can't show evacuated agents (count turtles with [pcolor = green]) in monitor box and number of evacuated in duration in plot space (plot count turtles with [pcolor = green]).
[image]

[image]
Would you please guide me how to solve these problems?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is a fair amount of code to go through, with sliders etc for people here to sort through. You may have better luck if you try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than posting your entire code. At a glance, note that you may be mixing up `color` and `pcolor`- turtles can be green without being on a green patch, which may be interfering with your `stop` condition.

Comment: Sina- great work, glad you sorted it out!